# Usar findViewById na MapsActivity padrão do Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

Estou usando o modelo padrão de Maps disponível no **Android Studio**, e na `activity_maps.xml` adicionei um `EditText` com o id *towhere*.

Na classe MapsActivity apenas adicionei um setOnFocusChangeListener:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if(mapFragment != null)
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        /* início da parte feita por mim */
        EditText towhere =  findViewById(R.id.towhere); //ERRO
        towhere.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus) {
                    Intent findAddress = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, FindAddress.class);
                    startActivity(findAddress);
                }
            }
        });
        /* fim da parte feita por mim */
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
    }
}
```

Recebo o erro:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.EditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(android.view.View$OnFocusChangeListener)'
>   on a null object reference

O `setContentView` está definido antes do `findViewById`, mas não funciona.

Comment: Para te ajudar vai ser preciso mais código (MapsActivity e o activity_maps.xml)

Comment: poste mais parte do código

Comment: Postei toda a classe, já que só adicionei algumas linhas e ela é curta.

Answer (score 0):

O problema estava no XML. Como eu estou rodando o emulador do Nexus, ele está obtendo o componente da pasta `layout-v26` ao invés da `layout`, e os arquivos `activity_maps.xml` dessas duas pastas estavam diferentes, e por isso estava dando NullPointerException para o id requisitado em `findViewById(R.id.towhere)`